# Connect to samba "windows share" of my router

Tags: samba, shared-folders

My router has an option for sharing to all connected computer the content of an USB key I connected to it. On the configuration page of the router (`http://192.168.1.1/service/samba`) I have :

```
Group name : WORKGROUP
Service name : Box
Sharing name : PartageBox
Share folder : / (which is my USB key root)
```

And from here, what should I do ? I think the router is correctly configured (it says that my device is shared), but I don't know how to connect to it.

I am connected to my router wifi. I tried to connect via samba, but I get an error:

```
me@GLaDOS:~$ smbclient -L //192.168.1.1
protocol negotiation failed: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_DISCONNECTED
```

Connection to `192.168.1.1/Box` and to `192.168.1.1/PartageBox` give the same error.

If needed, my router is from the french Internet provider SFR

Comment: Does adding `-mSMB3` to the command help? If not, what about `-mSMB2` or even `-mSMB1`?

Comment: The 3 possibilities result in `do_connect: Connection to -mSMB3 failed (Error NT_STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL)`

Comment: One more to try. What about `--option="client min protocol = NT1"` (instead of the `-mSMBx`)

Comment: That worked ! `smbclient -L 192.168.1.1 --option="client min protocol = NT1"`. Now it's asking my for a password... No idea what it is, but I'll look for it

Comment: Found it. Had to force encryption method (I think?) by adding `--option="client lanman auth = yes"` and `--option="client ntlmv2 auth = no"`. Final connection is done with `smbclient //192.168.1.1/PartageBox --option="client lanman auth = yes" --option="client ntlmv2 auth = no" --option="client min protocol = NT1" -U sayanel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was `smb` protocol version (thanks Roaima), I had to force v1 with

```
smbclient -L 192.168.1.1 --option="client min protocol = NT1"
```

Then, system prompted me for my password, so I had to add `-U myUser` to connect with the correct username.

After entering my password, I had this message

```
Server requested LANMAN password (share-level security) but 'client lanman auth = no' or 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes'
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

So I had to force the use of `lanman` and disable `ltlmn2`. The final command for listing server of this client is:

```
smbclient -L 192.168.1.1 --option="client lanman auth = yes" --option="client ntlmv2 auth = no" --option="client min protocol = NT1" -U sayanel
```

And the command for connecting to the shared folder is:

```
smbclient //192.168.1.1/PartageBox --option="client lanman auth = yes" --option="client ntlmv2 auth = no" --option="client min protocol = NT1" -U sayanel
```